# Date/Time Stamp Based on field entry

Tags: ms-access

I have two fields,

Allocated & Date Allocated

As soon as the field Allocated is filled with correct data

i would like date allocated to date/time stamp?

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's in a form it's pretty easy. Not so much so if you're looking at the raw table.

In a Form just right click on txtAllocated and select "Build Event" then "Code".

```
Private Sub txtAllocated_Update()
txtDateAllocated = Now()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the BeforeUpdate event of Allocated to include a timestamp:

```
Me!DateAllocated.Value = Now
```

Comment: Think? Did you even try? It will fill DateAllocated as soon Allocated gets updated.

Answer (score 0):

If this is in a table then there aren't a lot of options. Access is pretty limited when it comes to automatic table updates without using some kind of update query. I would just make another table with a linked ID to your main table with the allocated and dateAllocated fields. Then set the default value of the dateAllocated field to today's date.